# Summing and then getting min and max of top 70% in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data for the purchases of a product formatted like this:

```
Item  |  Price  |  Quantity Bought

ABC      10.10     4
DEF      8.30      12
DEF      7.75      8
ABC      10.50     20
GHI      15.4      1
GHI      15.2      12
ABC      10.25     8
...      ...       ...
```

Where each row represents an individual purchasing a certain amount at a certain price.  I would like to aggregate this data and eliminate the prices below the 30th percentile for total quantity bought from my table.

For example, in the above data set the total amount of product ABC bought was (4+20+8) = 32 units, with average price = (4*10.10 + 8*10.25 + 20*10.50)/32 = 10.39.

I would like to organize the above data set like this:

```
Item  |  VWP   |  Total Vol  |  70th %ile min  |  70th %ile max
ABC      10.39    32            ???               ???
DEF      ...      20            ???               ???
GHI      ...      13            ???               ???
```

Where VWP is the volume weighted price, and the 70th %ile min/max represent the minimum and maximum prices within the top 70% of volume.

In other words, I want to eliminate the prices with the lowest volumes until I have 70% of the total volume for the day contained in the remaining prices.  I would then like to publish the min and max price for the ones that are left in the 70th %ile min/max columns.

I tried to be as clear as possible, but if this is tough to follow along with please let me know which parts need clarification.

Note: These are not the only columns contained in my dataset, and I will be selecting and calculating other values as well.  I only included the columns that are relevant to this specific calculation.

**EDIT:**

Here is my code so far, and I need to incorporate my calculation into this (the variables with the '@' symbol before them are inputs that are given by the user:

```
SELECT Item, 
   SUM(quantity) AS Total_Vol, 
   DATEADD(day, -@DateOffset, CONVERT(date, GETDATE())) AS buyDate,
   MIN(Price) AS MinPrice,
   MAX(Price) AS MaxPrice,
   MAX(Price) - MIN(Price) AS PriceRange,
   ROUND(SUM(Price * quantity)/SUM(quantity), 6) AS VWP,

FROM TransactTracker..CustData
-- @DateOffset (Number of days data is offset by)
-- @StartTime (Time to start data in hours)
-- @EndTime (Time to stop data in hours)

WHERE DATEDIFF(day, TradeDateTime, GETDATE()) = (@DateOffset+1)
AND DATEPART(hh, TradeDateTime) >= @StartTime
AND HitTake = ''

OR DATEDIFF(day, TradeDateTime, GETDATE()) = @DateOffset
AND DATEPART(hh, TradeDateTime) < @EndTime
AND HitTake = ''

GROUP BY Item
```

**EDIT 2:**

```
FROM (SELECT p.*,
(SELECT SUM(quantity) from TransactTracker..CustData p2 
    where p2.Series = p.Series and p2.Size >= p.Size) as volCum
FROM TransactTracker..CustData p
) p
```

**EDIT 3:**

```
(case when CAST(qcum AS FLOAT) / SUM(quantity) <= 0.7 THEN MIN(Price) END) AS min70px,
(case when CAST(qcum AS FLOAT) / SUM(quantity) <= 0.7 THEN MAX(Price) END) AS max70px


FROM (select p.*,
  (select SUM(quantity) from TransactTracker..CustData p2 
  where p2.Item = p.Item and p2.quantity >= p.quantity) 
  as qcum from TransactTracker..CustData p) cd
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by 70% of volume. Can you include an example of actual numbers you want returned in the `min` and `max` columns and further explanation, please?

Comment: I believe he wants the `min` and `max` price values for 70% of the sales of each product.

Comment: if you fill in the first row with exact expected values, that will help.

Item  |  VWP   |  Total Vol  |  70th %ile min  |  70th %ile max
ABC      10.39    32            ???               ???

Comment: Does anyone know how to incorporate the calculation in Gordon's post into the code I posted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is some ambiguity on how you define 70 % when something goes over the threshold. However, the challenge is two fold.  After identifying the cumulative proportion, the query also needs to choose the appropriate row.  This suggests using `row_number()` for selection.

This solution using SQL Server 2012 syntax calculates the cumulative sum.  It then takes assigns a sequential value based on how close the ratio is to 70%.

```
select item,
       SUM(price * quantity) / SUM(quantity) as vwp,
       SUM(quantity) as total_vol,
       min(case when seqnum = 1 then price end) as min70price,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then price end) as max70price
from (select p.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by item order by abs(0.7 - qcum/qtot) as seqnum
      from (select p.*,
                   SUM(quantity) over (partition by item order by vol desc) as qcum,
                   SUM(quantity) over (partition by item) as qtot
            from purchases p
           ) p
     ) p
group by item;
```

To get the largest value less than 70%, then you would use:

```
max(case when qcum < qtot*0.7 then qcum end) over (partition by item) as lastqcum
```

And then the `case` statements in the outer select would be:

```
min(case when lastqcum = qcum then price end) . .
```

In earlier versions of SQL Server, you can get the same effect with the correlated subquery:

```
select item,
       SUM(price * quantity) / SUM(quantity) as vwp,
       SUM(quantity) as total_vol,
       min(case when seqnum = 1 then price end) as min70price,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then price end) as max70price
from (select p.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by item order by abs(0.7 - qcum/qtot) as seqnum
      from (select p.*,
                   (select SUM(quantity) from purchases p2 where p2.item = p.item and p2.quantity >= p.quantity
                   ) as qsum,
                   SUM(quantity) over (partition by item) as qtot
            from purchases p
           ) p
     ) p
group by item
```

Here is the example with your code:

```
SELECT Item, 
   SUM(quantity) AS Total_Vol, 
   DATEADD(day, -@DateOffset, CONVERT(date, GETDATE())) AS buyDate,
   MIN(Price) AS MinPrice,
   MAX(Price) AS MaxPrice,
   MAX(Price) - MIN(Price) AS PriceRange,
   ROUND(SUM(Price * quantity)/SUM(quantity), 6) AS VWP,
   min(case when seqnum = 1 then price end) as min70price,
   max(case when seqnum = 1 then price end) as max70price
from (select p.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by item order by abs(0.7 - qcum/qtot) as seqnum
      from (select p.*,
                   (select SUM(quantity) from TransactTracker..CustData p2 where p2.item = p.item and p2.quantity >= p.quantity
                   ) as qsum,
                   SUM(quantity) over (partition by item) as qtot
            from purchases TransactTracker..CustData
           ) p
     ) cd
-- @DateOffset (Number of days data is offset by)
-- @StartTime (Time to start data in hours)
-- @EndTime (Time to stop data in hours)

WHERE DATEDIFF(day, TradeDateTime, GETDATE()) = (@DateOffset+1)
AND DATEPART(hh, TradeDateTime) >= @StartTime
AND HitTake = ''

OR DATEDIFF(day, TradeDateTime, GETDATE()) = @DateOffset
AND DATEPART(hh, TradeDateTime) < @EndTime
AND HitTake = ''

GROUP BY Item
```

Comment: This seems like it is what I'm looking for, however I am unsure how to add this to my existing code.  Would you mind editing your post to show how I would add it in with my other pieces of data?

Comment: @weskpga . . . Use a subquery instead of `TransactTracker..CustData` and inside that subquery define `qcum` (using either method).  Then add the variables in the outer `select`.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm relatively new to SQL in general.  Could you briefly show me what that means?

Comment: I am not using SQL Server 2012 unfortunately.  How would it be written with the correlated subquery method?

Comment: The code I am trying is under my EDIT 2, and I am getting the error "Msg 130, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery."

Comment: I tried the method you just updated and I am still getting the same exact error.

Comment: @weskpga . . . Totally my fault.  I put the `min()` and `max()` in the wrong place.  Fixed.

Comment: I am now getting the error: 

Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
Column 'cd.volCum' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Where 'volCum' is the same thing as 'qcum' in your example.